# is there a way to have a file attachment in excel that can be accessed from multiple different computers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document with an inserted file attachment. Problem is, when I try to open the file from a computer that is not my own it says that it is unable to find the source. The file opens perfectly when on my own computer though. Is there any way to upload the file attachment so that it is saved within excel and not just opening a linked file on the computer path?

Comment: when you insert a file in an Excel workbook you can check "link to file". Do NOT do that so your file will be properly attached.

Comment: Could you share the Screen Shot (Message) Excel pops while open the file,, I'm sure there must be Update Link button and has to be clicked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the article [Insert an object in your Excel spreadsheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-an-object-in-your-excel-spreadsheet-e73867b2-2988-4116-8d85-f5769ea435ba) mentioned, if you don't want to update the copied data when it changes in the source file, use an embedded object. The version of the source is embedded entirely in the workbook. If you copy information as an embedded object, the destination file requires more disk space than if you link the information.

When a user opens the file on another computer, he can view the embedded object without having access to the original data. Because an embedded object has no links to the source file, the object is not updated if you change the original data.

Based on my tests, to attach an Existing File in Excel sheet, please don't select the **Link to File** check box. If it is selected, it will add a link to the file instead of embedding the file into Excel workbook. You can select **Display as Icon** to insert an icon that represents the contents of the file into your workbook. In addition, embedding an object in excel increases the Excel file size.

[image]